# Apply a CSS to all the elements of a particular div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="div1">
  <div>
   <p>
    <a href="#"></a>
   </p>
   <span></span>
  </div>
  <p>Loremp Loremp</p>
  <p>Loremp Loremp</p>
  <a href="#">Loremp Loremp</a>
  <span>Hello World</span>

 </div>

 <div class="div2">
  <p>Loremp Loremp</p>
  <p>Loremp Loremp</p>
  <a href="#">Loremp Loremp</a>
  <span>Hello World</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way for me to target all the elements of `div1` without that being applied on `div2`?

What I want to do is to make the CSS code very simple without having to target each element of `div1` one by one.

```css
/*I want to make something like that but without affecting the div2*/

*{
 color: blue;
}
```

Comment: `#div1 * { color: blue; }`

Comment: The `#` denotes the `id` property, but the `div` uses the `class` property. You should use `.div1` instead of `#div1`.

Comment: @alesc right you are, didn't look closely enough :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put

```
.div1 * {
 color: blue;
}
```

Or even better, just

```
.div1 {
 color: blue;
}
```

In my first block of code, all subelements of elements with class `div1` will have `color: blue` applied.

In the second block of code, only the elements with class `div1` will have `color: blue` applied, *but* all subelements will also inherit it (unless they override it). Therefore the effect *should* be the same.

Comment: Also consider the answer by [Bruno Toffolo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36411030/4623467) in which he noted that using `*` is very inefficient and therefore discouraged.

Comment: The question, I ask, is related to this post of mine: [go to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403993/modify-the-gap-between-two-divs)

And just doing 
```.container *,
.container *:after,
.container *:before {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}```

When I try with just `.container {...`, it does not work.

Comment: Not all CSS properties are inherited. For example, the `color`property will be inherited by subelements, but `box-sizing`, `padding`, and `margin` won't. That's why just using `.container` doesn't work in your example and you need to use `.container *`.

Comment: Do you have a better code to advice based on what I am facing on the post I shared?

Comment: Well, the same principle applies - you should get rid of the `*` selector either by rewriting the `demo.css` or by using a different library.

Comment: What I am going to ask would seem to be crazy to you, but can you help me rewrite the ``demo.css`` ?

I have been trying to solve that problem, but no way. And now the method I have found is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

first, **NO**: Using `.div1 *` will eventually bite you in the ass.

Best would be to apply the style to `.div1 {...}` and rely on the inheritance.

If you have like text in div1, that you don't want to style you may want to apply the style to the (direct) child-nodes of div1: `.div1 > * {...}`. And rely from this point on, on the inheritance.

Anything more specific like the example proposed on top will have unexpected side-effects and will drive you onto a way where you will have to increase the Specificity of your selectors more and more. 
Leading to things like `.div1 p ul li .foo div span.bar {...}` and overriding it with `.div1 p ul li .foo div span.bar * {...}` and so on. (dramatized)

If your problem are the links in your markup, you shoold consider a generic "reset"/modification of the link-tags so that they fit better into the surrounding text: sth. like.

```
a,
a:active {
    color: inherit;
}
```

and maybe you want to restrict even this to a specific context, like `.main`

**Edit:**

OK, P.Lionel, that is a different thing; I agree.
Using `.someSliderPluginClassName * { box-sizing: border-box }` is an appropriate way to implement this fast and easy, and it has a manageable amount of risk.

You are using `.container` (as in your comment) as kind of context for the elements of this slider-plugin and give all control over to this plugin. (Almost) nothing you have to handle/style in this context.

On the other hand, you may consider the migration of your styles to `box-sizing: border-box`. Imo. it's the better and more consistent boxing-model, and more and more plugins (and css-frameworks) rely on that.

I know, it's kind of an effort now, but it might pay off in the future. *Just my 5 cents.*

Comment: Good explanation. I think it meant to be `.div1 a {color:inherit;}`.

Comment: The question, I ask, is related to this post of mine: [go to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403993/modify-the-gap-between-two-divs) . 

Everything works when I use ```.container *, .container *:after, .container *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; } ``` When I try with just ``.container {...`` , it does not work.

Do you have a better code to advice based on the post I just shared?

Comment: For this special usage, I would agree. I've edited my Answer to account on that.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS selector with the name of the class you specified for the `div` attribute in your HTML.

```
.div1 {
   color: blue;
}
```

**Tip:** avoid using universal selectors in CSS (such as `.div1 * {`. Even as it has [negligent performance overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951997/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-csss-universal-selector), it can [have impacts you are not accounting for](http://www.kobashicomputing.com/avoid-using-universal-css-selector), besides being the [least efficient selector](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) available.

Answer (score 1):

You can match all children with this selector:

```
.div * {

}
```

or if you want to match a particular element type:

```
.div * p {

}
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Property `color` was inherited by default. This means you just need to set this property on the parent element, then all child elements will automatically inherit it.

```
.div1{
 color: blue;
}
```